# How to round off a value but not in unit step

Tags: python, perl, bash, rounding

I am trying to round off couple of decimal values in bash using awk. Ex: if values is 6.79

```
awk 'BEGIN {rounded = sprintf("%.0f", 6.79); print rounded }'
```

this returns me 7.

Is there a way in which I can round off not to nearest integer (1,2,3,..)  but in steps of 0.5 (0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5...)

Any alternate ways to work in python or perl are also fine. Current way in python

```
python -c "from math import ceil; print round(6.79)"
```

also return 7.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl solution:

```
perl -e 'print sprintf("%1.0f",2 * shift) / 2'  -- 6.79
7
```

The trick is easy: multiply the number by two, round it, divide back.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a universal sub program for rounding with a given precision to the nearest value:
I give an example with the rounding you want, i.e. 0.5, I've tested it and it works perfectly even with negative floating points numbers

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

for(my $i=0; $i<100; $i++){
    my $x = rand 100;
    $x -= 50;
    my $y =&roundToNearest($x,0.5);
    print "$x --> $y\n";
} 
exit;

############################################################################
# Enables to round any real number to the nearest with a given precision even for negative numbers
#  argument 1 : the float to round
# [argument 2 : the precision wanted]
#
# ie: precision=10 => 273 returns 270
# ie: no argument for precision means precision=1 (return signed integer) =>  -3.67 returns -4
# ie: precision=0.01 => 3.147278 returns 3.15

sub roundToNearest{

  my $subname = (caller(0))[3];
  my $float = $_[0];
  my $precision=1;
  ($_[1]) && ($precision=$_[1]);
  ($float) || return($float);  # no rounding needed for 0

  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  my $rounded = int($float/$precision + 0.5*$float/abs($float))*$precision;
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------

  #print  "$subname>precision:$precision float:$float --> $rounded\n";

  return($rounded);
}
```